# Mac and EFI secure boot

Tags: mac, efi, secure-boot

I've recently had a linux live USB completely fail to boot on a mac running El Capitan, which makes me suspect secure boot is rearing its ugly head in the Apple world, as well as the PC world. So my question is thus: does, or has Apple ever used EFI secure boot?

Comment: I know apple uses its own bootloader. And it has an addon which can emulate bios for using bootcamp to install windows. It should be able to run linux however. Although there is this update in El Captian which may be what you are running into. [Read about it Here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/sip.html)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. I don't think that has anything to do with EFI or secure boot. SIP just keeps you from accessing certain parts of the system, even as root, except when in recovery mode. It's a serious PITA, but AFAIK nothing to do with secure boot.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, Apple does not currently support Secure Boot on any of its computers. If I'm wrong about that, it would be only on *very* recent models. Chances are your problem has some other cause. Providing specifics on your computer's model, the type of Linux you're trying to run (Ubuntu, Fedora, etc.), how you prepared the USB drive (`dd`, Rufus, UNetbootin, etc.), and what failure symptoms you're seeing (boots to OS X, GRUB followed by a blank screen, error messages, etc.) would be helpful in diagnosing your problem. Without that information, any suggested solution will be a wild guess.